# How to list the contents of a nested archive (.gz)

Tags: unix, nested, archive, tar, gzip

I have a compressed archive (archives.tar.gz) of compressed archives f1.tar.gz, f2.tar.gz, f3.tar.gz...

I would like to list the contents of a sub archive file, say f1.tar.gz, without actually upacking and extracting everything. In other words, I need to be able to do something like: tar -ztvf f1.tar.gz without first having to do: tar -zxvf archives.tar.gz

Any ideas on how to do this?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

There's no real way to do this without incurring some of the overhead of uncompressing the archive, because of the nature of the compression.  If you want to avoid creating intermediate files, you can do this:

```
tar -zxOf archives.tar.gz f1.tar.gz | tar -ztf -
```

That will extract only `f1.tar.gz` from the archive and feed it to the second tar, which will list the files.

Comment: Thanks Jim, your solution makes sense but I'm unsure about the hyphen at the very end. What does that do? I couldn't get it to work with exactly this syntax (hyphen at the end), but I was able to make it work by specifying the file name after the second tar: 

tar -zxvf archives.tar.gz f1.tar.gz | tar -ztf f1.tar.gz

...only downside here is that I'm left with the intermediate f1.tar.gz

Comment: The hyphen on the end tells it to read from standard input.  It has to follow the `f`, because it's used as the filename.  Using `-` as a filename in Unix is a convention for "read from standard input instead of opening a file".  If you're adding other flags in (say `v`), make sure they're before the `f`.

Comment: Cool - so I tried it again...

//this way I didn't get any result
matt# tar -zxvf log_backup_112912.tar.gz ./booksite-1.0-event.log.tar.gz | tar -tvf -
matt#

# tar -zxvf archives.tar.gz ./.tar.gz | tar -tvf ./booksite*
-rw-r--r-- root/root    556504 2012-11-27 23:16:43 ./booksite-1.0-event.log.121127

Comment: Sorry, I inadvertently posted that before I was done editing. Here are my edited comments:<br/><br/>

I tried it again but for some reason it did not return anything. However, it should because in the example below I know the file ./booksite-1.0-event.log.tar.gz is not empty. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again for your help!<br/><br/>

//this way I didn't get any result...<br/>
matt# tar -zxvf log_backup_112912.tar.gz ./booksite-1.0-event.log.tar.gz | tar -tvf -<br/>
matt#

Comment: Try removing the leading `./` from the booksite path.  Do a `tar ztf log_backup_112912.tar.gz` to see the exact names of the sub-archives in the top level one.

Comment: Thank you for this!
I needed to view the contents of a jar inside a tar distribution created by gradle.

I had to use `jar` instead of `unzip` in my use case as I guess archives from stdin are not yet supported: 
"Archives read from standard input are not yet supported, except with funzip (and then only the first member of the archive can be extracted)."
`tar -xOf server/build/distributions/server.tar server.jar | jar -t` works perfectly